# Disable expand/collapse in swagger-ui

Tags: javascript, swagger-ui

We are using the latest npm version of swagger-ui in our frontend app. We have some familiarity with customising its experience via the plugins. Does anyone know if it is possible to disable the expand/collapse functionality on the operations and/or tags via the plugin api? I.e. we want everything to be permanently expanded

Comment: Consider asking in the project's GitHub repo, you might get a better/faster answer there: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues

Comment: @Helen thanks, I’ve submitted here -> https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/6347